# Choosing sets from Subset[list]

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, subset

Say I have a set, S, and I take Subsets[S] (the power set of S). For example:

```
S={a,b,c}
Subsets[S]={{}, {a}, {b}, {c}, {a, b}, {a, c}, {b, c}, {a, b, c}}
```

How can I make a list which takes only sets which have an element of a subset, but not the whole set. Ideally, using the example above, something like this:

```
f[Subsets[S],a]={{a},{a,b},{a,c}}
```

Further, say I have a set of subsets. Using the above example:

```
L={{a},{b}}
```

How can I choose the elements from Subsets[S] so that any of the elements of L are subsets, but not including the whole set. Again, using the above:

```
g[Subsets[S],L]={{a},{b},{a,b},{a,c},{b,c}}
```

Ideally, `g` could be generalized for any power set and set of subsets.

Any help would be ***greatly*** appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my attempt to cover the generalized case that you describe. I went ahead and made it even a little bit more general, as the tests will show.

#### Solution:

```
SelectSubsets[S_, el : Except[_List]] := SelectSubsets[S, {el}]
SelectSubsets[S_, lists : {{__} ..}] := SelectSubsets[S, #] & /@ lists
SelectSubsets[S_, list_] := Cases[Subsets[S], Except[S,
   Prepend[___]@Append[___]@Riffle[ConstantArray[Alternatives @@ list, Length@list], ___]
   ]]
```

#### Tests:

```
S = {a, b, c, d};
SelectSubsets[S, a]
```

> `{{a}, {a, b}, {a, c}, {a, d}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, d}, {a, c, d}}`

```
SelectSubsets[S, {a, b}]
```

> `{{a, b}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, d}}`

```
SelectSubsets[S, {{a}, {b}}]
```

> `{{{a}, {a, b}, {a, c}, {a, d}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, d}, {a, c, d}}, {{b},
>   {a, b}, {b, c}, {b, d}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, d}, {b, c, d}}}`

```
Union @@ SelectSubsets[S, {{a}, {b}}]
```

> `{{a}, {b}, {a, b}, {a, c}, {a, d}, {b, c}, {b, d}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, d}, {a, c, d}, {b, c, d}}`

```
SelectSubsets[S, {{a, b}, {b, d}}]
```

> `{{{a, b}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, d}}, {{b, d}, {a, b, d}, {b, c, d}}}`

#### Explanation

`SelectSubsets` is implemented in terms of `Cases[list, form]` which compares every element in `list` to the pattern `form` in order to determine if it should be included in the result.

`Except` is used in the pattern to remove the full set from the list:

```
S = {a, b, c};
Cases[Subsets[S], Except[S]]
```

> `{{}, {a}, {b}, {c}, {a, b}, {a, c}, {b, c}}`

The heart of the solution is this pattern:

```
Prepend[___]@Append[___]@Riffle[ConstantArray[Alternatives @@ list, Length@list], ___]
```

For example if `list` is `{a, b}` then this results in

```
{___, a|b, ___, a|b, ___}
```

and if `list` is `{a, b, c}` it evaluates to

```
{___, a|b|c, ___, a|b|c, ___, a|b|c, ___}
```

So, this pattern will find every subset that includes `a`, `b`, and `c`.

The more complex inputs can be handled using the pattern described above. You will find that the two first definitions of `SelectSubsets` are just ways to do what they are supposed to do in terms of this pattern.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Instead of Except[S,...], what if I wanted to exclude all subsets which contained a specific set. 

Also, if I wanted to exclude sets which weren't the union of elements of  the list of lists. For example:

`S={1,2,3,4,a,b,c,d}`,
`exclude.sets.containing={1,2,3,4}`,
`L={{a,1,4},{b,1,2},{c,2,3},{d,3,4}}`.

Then `f[S,N,L]=Union[L,{{a,b,1,2,4},{a,d,1,3,4},{b,c,1,2,3},{c,d,2,3,4}}]`

This may be an entirely different question, perhaps I should make another post? I am unsure of the protocol.

Comment: @jix816 Start by reading the documentation for `Except`, could it be as simple as moving what is now the second argument to the first argument of `Except`? I think it would be better if you asked at least the second question as a new question, as you suggested, but make sure to mention this question.

Comment: I will do just that. Thank you very much for your assistance!

Answer (score 2):

To not generate all subsets we can do something like:

```
ClearAll[sel]
sel[el_, set_] := Flatten[#, 1] & /@ Most @ Tuples[{
     Rest @ Subsets[el], 
     Subsets @ DeleteCases[set, Alternatives @@ el]
}]
```

---

```
sel[{a}, {a, b, c}]
```

> ```
> {{a}, {a, b}, {a, c}}
> ```

```
sel[{a, b}, {a, b, c}]
```

> ```
> {{a}, {a, c}, {b}, {b, c}, {a, b}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `SubsetQ[list1,list2]` which is `True` exactly if `list2` is a subset of `list1`. So define

```
SubsetLQ[list1_,listoflists_]:=And@@(SubsetQ[list1,#]&/@listoflists)
```

This should give you `True` exactly if all elements of `listoflists` are a subset of `list1`. Then use

```
Select[Subsets[S],SubsetLQ[#,L]&&Length@#<Length@S&]
```

This should work, provided I understood correctly what you are looking for

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

**Update** with more general solution that makes at most one extra subset and works when `items` are not in `set`.

```
h[set_List, items_List] :=
 With[{comp = Complement[set, items]},
  Select[Length@# != Length@comp + Length@items &]@
   Flatten[Outer[Flatten@*Join, Subsets[items, {1, Length@items}], Subsets[comp], 1], 1]
  ]

h[{a, b, c}, {a}]
(* {{a}, {a, b}, {a, c}} *)

h[{a, b, c}, {a, b}]
(* {{a}, {a, c}, {b}, {b, c}, {a, b}} *)

h[{a, b, c}, {f}]
(* {{f}, {f, a}, {f, b}, {f, c}, {f, a, b}, {f, a, c}, {f, b, c}} *)
```

---

**Original post**

`ContainsAny` with `Select` (twice).

```
g[set_List, items_List] := 
 Select[set != # &]@Select[ContainsAny[items]]@Subsets[set]

s = {a, b, c}; t = {a};
g[s, t]

(* {{a}, {a, b}, {a, c}} *)

t = {{a}, {b}};
g[s, Flatten@t]

(* {{a}, {b}, {a, b}, {a, c}, {b, c}} *)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This helped very much. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select[Subsets[{a, b, c}], MemberQ[#, a] && Length@# < 3 &]
```

> {{a}, {a, b}, {a, c}}

```
Select[Subsets[{a, b, c}], MemberQ[#, a | b] && Length@# < 3 &]
```

> {{a}, {b}, {a, b}, {a, c}, {b, c}}

Comment: I really appreciate your help!