# Choosing sets from Subsets[list] part 2

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, subset

Piggybacking off of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104358/choosing-sets-from-subsetlist/104367#104367), say if I wanted to exclude sets which weren't the union of elements of the list of lists.

For example:

```
S={1,2,3,4,a,b,c,d}
exclude.sets.containing={1,2,3,4}
L={{a,1,4},{b,1,2},{c,2,3},{d,3,4}}.
```

Then `f[S,exclude.sets.containing,L]={{a,1,4},{b,1,2},{c,2,3},{d,3,4},{a,b,1,2,4},{a,d,1,3,4},{b,c,1,2,3},{c,d,2,3,4}}`

As you can see, each element of `f[S,exclude.sets.containing,L]` is generated by the union of elements of `L`, but does not contain `{1,2,3,4}`, which would be a larger output. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more elegant ways, but this works:

```
myL = {{a, 1, 4}, {b, 1, 2}, {c, 2, 3}, {d, 3, 4}, {a, b, 1, 2, 
   4}, {a, d, 1, 3, 4}, {b, c, 1, 2, 3}, {c, d, 2, 3, 4}};

myFullList = 
 Flatten[Table[
   Union[myL[[i]], myL[[j]]], 
 {i, Length[myL]}, {j, Length[myL]}], 1];

Select[myFullList, Not[SubsetQ[#, {1, 2, 3, 4}]]  &]
```

(*
{{1, 4, a}, {1, 2, 4, a, b}, {1, 3, 4, a, d}, {1, 2, 4, a, b}, {1, 3, 
  4, a, d}, {1, 2, 4, a, b}, {1, 2, b}, {1, 2, 3, b, c}, {1, 2, 4, a, 
  b}, {1, 2, 3, b, c}, {1, 2, 3, b, c}, {2, 3, c}, {2, 3, 4, c, 
  d}, {1, 2, 3, b, c}, {2, 3, 4, c, d}, {1, 3, 4, a, d}, {2, 3, 4, c, 
  d}, {3, 4, d}, {1, 3, 4, a, d}, {2, 3, 4, c, d}, {1, 2, 4, a, 
  b}, {1, 2, 4, a, b}, {1, 2, 4, a, b}, {1, 3, 4, a, d}, {1, 3, 4, a, 
  d}, {1, 3, 4, a, d}, {1, 2, 3, b, c}, {1, 2, 3, b, c}, {1, 2, 3, b, 
  c}, {2, 3, 4, c, d}, {2, 3, 4, c, d}, {2, 3, 4, c, d}}
*)

Comment: Thank you very much, this works wonderfully!